# what is the table design for this json request

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, database-table

**Request body**

```
{
    "standard": '',
    "section": '',
    "subject": '',
    "type" : '',
    "startTime": '',
    "allDayEvent": false,
    "startTimezone": '',
    "endTimezone": '',
    "endTime": ''  ,
    "repeat": {
        "frequency": 'Never',
        "interval": '',
        "recurrencePattern": {
            "weekly": {
            "weeklydaysOfWeek": null
        },
        "monthly": {
            "monthlydayOfMonth": 0,
            "monthlyIndex": '',
            "monthlydayOfWeek": null                       
        },
        "yearly": {
            "month": 0,
            "yearlydayOfMonth": 0,
            "yearlyIndex": '',
            "yearlydayOfWeek": null                  
        }
    },
    "until":{
        "neverFlag": false,
        "occurrence": 0,
        "endDate": null
    }
}
```

how many tables can i create for this and in weeklydaysofweek we will get multiple days so how can i store those week days seperatly.i have to provide details based on the enddate it is in until object.

Comment: You could put it all in one big JSON field.

Comment: @Teja Sree What db u r using?

Comment: @ArunSai MySql WorkBench

Comment: From 1 to 7 (you may create more tables but this will be absolutely unreasonable). The most reasonable amount seems to be 4 tables.

Comment: @Tejasree , "MySql WorkBench" is not a database, it's a tool for database. To confirm you're using MySQL, run `SELECT version();` in workbench and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

Check below SQL

```
/* CREATE TABLE */
CREATE TABLE test(
`standard` VARCHAR(100),
`section` VARCHAR(100),
`subject` VARCHAR(100),
`type` VARCHAR(100),
`startTime` VARCHAR(100),
`allDayEvent` VARCHAR(100),
`startTimezone` VARCHAR(100),
`endTimezone` VARCHAR(100),
`endTime` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatfrequency` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatinterval` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatrecurrencePatternweeklyweeklydaysOfWeek` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatrecurrencePatternmonthlymonthlydayOfMonth` DOUBLE,
`repeatrecurrencePatternmonthlymonthlyIndex` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatrecurrencePatternmonthlymonthlydayOfWeek` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatrecurrencePatternyearlymonth` DOUBLE,
`repeatrecurrencePatternyearlyyearlydayOfMonth` DOUBLE,
`repeatrecurrencePatternyearlyyearlyIndex` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatrecurrencePatternyearlyyearlydayOfWeek` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatuntilneverFlag` VARCHAR(100),
`repeatuntiloccurrence` DOUBLE,
`repeatuntilendDate` VARCHAR(100)
);

/* INSERT QUERY NO: 1 */
INSERT INTO test(`standard`, `section`, `subject`, `type`, `startTime`, `allDayEvent`, `startTimezone`, `endTimezone`, `endTime`, `repeatfrequency`, `repeatinterval`, `repeatrecurrencePatternweeklyweeklydaysOfWeek`, `repeatrecurrencePatternmonthlymonthlydayOfMonth`, `repeatrecurrencePatternmonthlymonthlyIndex`, `repeatrecurrencePatternmonthlymonthlydayOfWeek`, `repeatrecurrencePatternyearlymonth`, `repeatrecurrencePatternyearlyyearlydayOfMonth`, `repeatrecurrencePatternyearlyyearlyIndex`, `repeatrecurrencePatternyearlyyearlydayOfWeek`, `repeatuntilneverFlag`, `repeatuntiloccurrence`, `repeatuntilendDate`)
VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', 'false', '', '', '', 'Never', '', '', 0, '', '', 0, 0, '', '', 'false', 0, '');
```